# Jenkins job doesn't fail when docker login command fails

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote a stage in a jenkins pipeline in order to push a docker image to a registry, but pipeline doesn't abort when docker login command fails :

```
make push BUILD_ID=733
for i in tomcat ; do cd $i ; make login &&  make push TAG=latest && make push ; cd - ; done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jenkins/workspace/CTO/CSF/Common/CSF-DOCKER/tomcat'
sudo docker login -u **** -p "****" csf-docker-candidate.repo.lab.pl.alcatel-lucent.com
Error response from daemon: Login: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Unsupported docker v1 repository request for 'csf-docker-candidate'"
  } ]
} (Code: 400; Headers: map[Date:[Mon, 13 Nov 2017 11:35:21 GMT] Server:[Artifactory/5.4.6] X-Artifactory-Id:[ff6eb7375fefa75b:-9fef662:15e7accbf81:-7ffd] Content-Type:[application/json]])
make[1]: *** [login] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jenkins/workspace/CTO/CSF/Common/CSF-DOCKER/tomcat'
/home/jenkins/workspace/CTO/CSF/Common/CSF-DOCKER 
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

what thing to add in order to abort the pipeline when the docker command fails;

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline does not fail, because your bash command succeeds. failure of your make command is hidden by success of "cd" after semicolon. You should make your command to exit loop on error and then fail whole script - see similar question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241178/how-can-i-get-this-script-to-error-exit-based-on-result-of-for-loop

Comment: for i in $(BUILDSEQ) ; do cd $$i ; (make login || exit 1) &&  (make push TAG=latest || exit 1) && (make push || exist 1) ; cd - ; done  , i did that but still the same probelm

Comment: for loop still exits with 0, because `; cd - ;` is valid

Comment: combine `cd -` with `&&`, not `;` -  As I understand, you want to fail on first error. If so, you don't need to cd back - Jenkins job will do fine if you stay in folder. However if you want to "clean-up" after job, use try-finally in Jenkinsfile and place `cd -` in finally block

Comment: for i in $(BUILDSEQ) ; do cd $$i ; make login || exit 1 && make push TAG=latest || exit 1 && make push || exist 1; cd - ; done; this ithink it worked

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work when make login succeeds. Now it's ok, becuase make login fails so first `exit 1` triggers. But if I'm correct, `make push TAG=latest` will never be executed because if `make login` succeeds, everything after fist `||` till the `;` will be skipped. Why do you need to use semicolons after cd anyway?

Comment: so you suggest the following : for i in $(BUILDSEQ) ; do cd $$i ; make login && make push TAG=latest && make push && cd - || exit 1 ; done ;

Comment: right @Miq ? this would work and we won't have the problem you said above

Comment: yes. I would even add `&&` after `cd $$i`. It's no point in executing `make login` if cd into desired folder failed.